# Can I use yahoo-kafka-manager if I don't have sbt locally?

Tags: java, sbt, apache-kafka, yahoo-kafka-manager

I want to visualize kafka cluster and I've found out that 
yahoo's [kafka-manager](https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager) is good tool for this.

[The github link](https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager) says I should use `sbt` I didn't use it before and I am not sure that I need to install additional PO on my pc.

Can I just download jar file or something like this?

Answer (score 1):

SBT is easy to install - just [download zip file](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html) & unpack it.
If you don't want to install anything, but have Docker, then you can select from a number of [Docker builds](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=kafka-manager&starCount=0).

Comment: I don't have docker and I want to not install something useless for me. Is would be good to just have a jar file

Comment: Is there another(appropriate)location with jar?